# Ionic Framework 3 Error: Window Redirect Problems

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm  new in Ionic Framework, and I'm using version 3 to build a simple application that redirects the user to an **.html** page after logging in. I've edited the **home.ts** file to make the log in possible, and I've built a test **.html** called index.html, in the folder "pages/home" inside the ionic project, but I'm getting an error when I try to conned the "submit" button to this index.html page:

Code in **home.html**

```
  <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Login
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>User</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Senha</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <button block ion-button block (click)="signIn()">Sign in</button>

</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Code in **home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { index } from 'c:/Ionic/task-1/src/pages/home/index.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public username : any = '';
  public password : any = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) 
{

  }

  signIn() {

        this.navCtrl.push('index.html');
     }
   }
```

The code in **index.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Login
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

 <ion-content padding>
 <p>Testing HTML page redirect</p>

</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

The error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRivh.png

What could I do?

Comment: what is index.html in push method ?

Comment: paste your code structure and both page code so i will give you correct answer.

Comment: because you did lot of mistake

Comment: I've edited it with the code in all the pages. I need to redirect the user from "home" to "index" after the user logs in.

Comment: show me index.ts file

Comment: I didn't create a index.ts file because it's just a simple html5 page.

Comment: it is not pure javascript. you have to use way of ionic angular.

Comment: Then I should create a index.ts file? What should be in it since it's pure HTML that it contains?

Comment: you have create componenet like home.ts and check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ionic 3 you can navigate through pages using `NavController`.You should create a component that you want to route.

For that you have to import the component(page)

**HTML file**

```
<button block ion-button block (click)="signIn()">Sign in</button>
```

**TS file**

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StartPage } from './start-page';

@Component(
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

signIn() {
     this.navCtrl.push(StartPage);
  }
}
```

Refer `NavController` documentation in ionic
[check here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/)

Answer (score 1):

In home.ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IndexPage} from '../index/index';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public username : any = '';
  public password : any = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController){}

  signIn() {
     this.navCtrl.push(IndexPage);
  }
}
```